# Importing planet files into Nominatim

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql, postgis-2.0, centos

After a gruesome night installing PostgreSQL 9.1, PostGIS 2 and Nominatim 2 on CentOS 6.3 using the instructions [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation), I am finally at the stage of importing a US planet file.

**Problem:** In `~/Nominatim/utils`, When I attempt to run `./setup.php --osm-file us-northeast.osm.pbf --all`, the output I get is:

```
["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(9) {
          ["phptype"]=>
          string(5) "pgsql"
          ["dbsyntax"]=>
          string(5) "pgsql"
          ["username"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["password"]=>
          bool(false)
          ["protocol"]=>
          string(3) "tcp"
          ["hostspec"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["port"]=>
          bool(false)
          ["socket"]=>
          bool(false)
          ["database"]=>
          string(9) "nominatim"
        }
        [1]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
    [5]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(35) "/home/myusername/Nominatim/lib/db.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(7)
      ["function"]=>
      string(7) "connect"
      ["class"]=>
      string(2) "DB"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "::"
      ["args"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(19) "pgsql://@/nominatim"
        [1]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
    [6]=>
    array(4) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(40) "/home/myusername/Nominatim/utils/setup.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(118)
      ["function"]=>
      string(5) "getDB"
      ["args"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["callback"]=>
  NULL
}
DB Error: connect failed
```

and I am thrown back to the command line. I am logged in as a user who has a postgresql role of the same name and is a superuser. Any idea what went wrong? Do I need to create any database before doing this?

Comment: Have you edited your pg_hba.conf to allow connections correctly? http://serverfault.com/questions/61128/configuring-the-pg-hba-conf-file-to-allow-access-from-other-servers-to-the-datab

Comment: I added to `pg_hba.conf` the line `host all myusername 0.0.0.0/25 trust` and restarted postgresql-9.1, but I still get the error. Did I add this line incorrectly?

Comment: did you change the other file too? postgresql.conf listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: Yup that was changed to `*` too.

Comment: I updated the error message. Is it supposed to connect without a username and password?

Answer (score 1):

Per the Nominatim installation instructions, it expects the installation system user and the DB user are named the same, the DB installation user be a superuser AND the pg_hba.conf have trust set for that user.

So yes, it is expected to connect without providing a username / password.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to create base before. I have the same problem when I don't install all packages. Here you can see full instructions http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation